# Extract all the data between \" characters

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a line like this:

```
"[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\"]"
```

How do I extract all the data and create a json object ?

For example, if I have 10 values between this separator `\"`, I should get something like this:

```
var string = "[\"1\",\"2\",\"Example\",\"Hello world\",\"5\"]";
var obj = ... // Parser
                    
console.log(obj[0]); // Output 1
console.log(obj[1]); // Output 2
console.log(obj[2]); // Output Example
console.log(obj[3]); // Output Hello world
console.log(obj[4]); // Output 5
```

I can easily do this thanks to the loop. But how to do this with regular expressions :(
I need to create an array with the obtained knowledge between this `\"` separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very basic `JSON.parse()`

```js
const string = "[\"1\",\"2\",\"Example\",\"Hello world\",\"5\"]";
const arr = JSON.parse(string)// renamed to arr since result is array

console.log(arr[0]); // Output 1
console.log(arr[1]); // Output 2
console.log(arr[2]); // Output Example
console.log(arr[3]); // Output Hello world
console.log(arr[4]); // Output 5
```

Comment: Initially, I tried this option, but for some reason I didn't get what I expected, and I thought it was wrong. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Now if it is sent from server as json with those outer quotes it will be invalid json. It works here because the quotes tell js it is a string